# Mapping--definition problem

Tags: jsp, servlets

could anyone please tell me the meaning of the word **mapping** in the following line:

> When you define a servlet for a JSP,
>   you must also define mapping to the
>   JSP page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mapping == association == link == reference.